# TCP Connection Reset on ESXI 6.7

Tags: tcp, wireshark, vsphere, esxi, connection-reset

I am running windows and ubuntu clients on ESXi 6.7 on internet root server.

When entering some websites (“bbc.co.uk”,”web.de”) the webserver reset my TCP connection, the server send **ERR_CONNECTION_RESET**. All other websites work fine. For windows-update I got a TCP-Flag-Reset too.

*It seems to be redirection to https is not working.
I ve tried multiple DNS Server (like google, opendns, standard ISP). For Debugging there is no proxy and no firewall.*

Is the problem comes from my ESXi TCP-IP-Stack or wrong MAC adresses?

Wireshark Screenshots:

1. [Windows Update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DydK9.png)
2. [Standard Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPDwq.png)

Comment: Both captures are maybe not showing the same problem. Windows Update shows a RST after a clean SSL Hello and a FIN. The second shows a RST after a 3WHS. Maybe is there a middlebox (like F5 BIG-IP) between you and Internet, check the MAC address you see in your captures.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that driver problems causes this problem. My nic is not supported by esxi.